# Error Code: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i hava a query on mysql, and i like to get the date value.
here's the sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT pegawai.NIP_BARU, pegawai.NAMA_PEGAWAI, pegawai.KODE_PANGKAT_TERAKHIR,pangkat_golongan.NAMA_PANGKAT, pangkat_golongan.GOLONGAN, pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR, gaji.MASA_KERJA_GOLONGAN, gaji.NOMINAL_GAJI,CASE PEGAWAI.TMT_GOL
WHEN (pangkat_golongan.JENIS_GOLONGAN = '2') AND pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR MOD 2 = 0 AND 12 - pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)> 12 THEN 2 + YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL)
WHEN (pangkat_golongan.JENIS_GOLONGAN = '1') AND pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR MOD 2 = 1 AND 12 - pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)> 12 THEN 2 + YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL)
WHEN (pangkat_golongan.JENIS_GOLONGAN = '1') AND pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR MOD 2 = 0 AND 12 - pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)< 12 THEN YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL)
WHEN (pangkat_golongan.JENIS_GOLONGAN = '2') AND pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR MOD 2 = 1 AND 12 - pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)< 12 THEN YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL)
ELSE 1 + YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL) END AS TAHUN_HITUNG,CASE PEGAWAI.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR
WHEN (12 -(pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR) + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL) > 12)
THEN (12 - (pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR) + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL) - 12)
ELSE (12 - (pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR) + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)) END AS BULAN_HITUNG, STR_TO_DATE(TAHUN_HITUNG, BULAN_HITUNG, '01','%Y-%m-%d') AS TMT_HITUNG FROM pegawai, gaji, pangkat_golongan WHERE gaji.KODE_GOLONGAN = pegawai.KODE_PANGKAT_TERAKHIR AND gaji.MASA_KERJA_GOLONGAN = pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR AND pangkat_golongan.KODE_PANGKAT = pegawai.KODE_PANGKAT_TERAKHIR;
```

and there's always error on this line

```
STR_TO_DATE(TAHUN_HITUNG, BULAN_HITUNG, '01','%Y-%m-%d') AS TMT_HITUNG
```

> Error Code: 1582
>   Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'

Comment: Its true.. str_to_date only wants 2 parameters and you have supplied 4 What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to convert the query result to date format... Soand its always on first date of the month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the MySQL documentation states, the `STR_TO_DATE` function takes only two parameters. [MySQL STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) The first parameter should be the string that you want to convert, and the second is the date format. It looks like you have the second and not the first.

Do you mean to concatenate the year, month, and date? Try this:
`STR_TO_DATE(concat(TAHUN_HITUNG,'-', BULAN_HITUNG,'-', '01'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS TMT_HITUNG`

**UPDATE**

I made your main query a subquery, and then applied the `str_to_date` function on the results of the subquery, selecting all of the other columns. You could also add your `tahun_hitung` and `bulan_hitung` to the first select list. You can't use aliases for your calculations as column names within the same `select` statement. That's why you were getting the `unknown column` error.

```
select NIP_BARU, NAMA_PEGAWAI, KODE_PANGKAT_TERAKHIR, NAMA_PANGKAT, 
GOLONGAN, MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR, MASA_KERJA_GOLONGAN, NOMINAL_GAJI,
STR_TO_DATE(concat(TAHUN_HITUNG,'-', BULAN_HITUNG,'-', '01'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS TMT_HITUNG 
from (
        SELECT DISTINCT pegawai.NIP_BARU, pegawai.NAMA_PEGAWAI, pegawai.KODE_PANGKAT_TERAKHIR,pangkat_golongan.NAMA_PANGKAT, pangkat_golongan.GOLONGAN, pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR, gaji.MASA_KERJA_GOLONGAN, gaji.NOMINAL_GAJI,CASE PEGAWAI.TMT_GOL
        WHEN (pangkat_golongan.JENIS_GOLONGAN = '2') AND pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR MOD 2 = 0 AND 12 - pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)> 12 THEN 2 + YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL)
        WHEN (pangkat_golongan.JENIS_GOLONGAN = '1') AND pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR MOD 2 = 1 AND 12 - pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)> 12 THEN 2 + YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL)
        WHEN (pangkat_golongan.JENIS_GOLONGAN = '1') AND pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR MOD 2 = 0 AND 12 - pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)< 12 THEN YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL)
        WHEN (pangkat_golongan.JENIS_GOLONGAN = '2') AND pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR MOD 2 = 1 AND 12 - pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)< 12 THEN YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL)
        ELSE 1 + YEAR(pegawai.TMT_GOL) END AS TAHUN_HITUNG,CASE PEGAWAI.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR
        WHEN (12 -(pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR) + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL) > 12)
        THEN (12 - (pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR) + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL) - 12)
        ELSE (12 - (pegawai.MASA_KERJA_BLN_AKHIR) + MONTH(pegawai.TMT_GOL)) END AS BULAN_HITUNG 
        FROM pegawai, gaji, pangkat_golongan 
        WHERE gaji.KODE_GOLONGAN = pegawai.KODE_PANGKAT_TERAKHIR AND gaji.MASA_KERJA_GOLONGAN = pegawai.MASA_KERJA_THN_AKHIR AND pangkat_golongan.KODE_PANGKAT = pegawai.KODE_PANGKAT_TERAKHIR
) subquery;
```

Comment: I have try this and looks like mysql doesnt know the TAHUN_HITUNG column. Its said unknown column 'TAHUN_HITUNG' in field list

Comment: Yay, thanks... 
How can I write a few query If i want to add another subquery using these same table.

Answer (score 0):

You pass 4 params here:

```
STR_TO_DATE(TAHUN_HITUNG, BULAN_HITUNG, '01','%Y-%m-%d')
```

[mysql doc here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: This isn't a solution, this is simply confirmation of the problem. Provide a solution else this isn't an answer!

Comment: You ask about source of error. this is explanation. You do not ask about solution.

Comment: @RomanChe He didn't ask for the source of the error, he asked for help fixing his code.

Comment: The answer could be improved with an correct example from the doc.